# BabylonJS compute ArcRotateCamera rotation to look at point on sphere

Tags: babylonjs

How do I compute the alpha and beta for ArcRotateCamera to look a point on a sphere? My playground has a ray from sphere origin to point on surface. Ultimately, I would like to animate from current point to ray.

```js
const vecToLocal = (vector, mesh) => {
    var m = mesh.getWorldMatrix();
    var v = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformCoordinates(vector, m);
    return v;        
}
const createScene = () => {

    const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 0, 0, 10, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0), scene);
    camera.setPosition(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, -10));
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

    const sphere = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateSphere("sphere", {
        diameter: 1
    },scene);
    sphere.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial('sphere-material')
    sphere.material.emissiveColor = BABYLON.Color3.White()

    const origin = sphere.position;
    const forward = vecToLocal(new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 0), sphere);

    const direction = BABYLON.Vector3.Normalize(forward.subtract(origin));
    const ray = new BABYLON.Ray(origin, direction, 2);

    BABYLON.RayHelper.CreateAndShow(ray, scene, new BABYLON.Color3(1, 0, 0));

    return scene;

};
```

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#SRZRWV#1225